# Hacer 1 compilacion Compilacion de exe y app.config

Tags: c#, .net, compilar

buenas tardes. Mi problema es que cuando hago el exe de un proyecto c#, lo saco de la carpeta Bin, y lo quiero llevar a otra pc, me arroja el error que no encuentra la cadena de conexion, la cual la tengo en el app.config. Use ilmerge para ver si podia unificar todo en un solo exe, pero no pude. Estoy olvidando algo? Dese ya muchas gracias.

Comment: nada.. tenes que mandar todos los archivos de tu carpeta bin.. no solo el exe... si hay dll externas tambien van en esa carpeta y debes mandarlas.. cual es el problema de mandarlo todo?

Comment: Hola, es que pense que habria alguna manera de solo mandar el exe, para que los archivos no sean accesados y quede algo mas prolijo, por eso consultaba esa parte... muchas gracias!

Comment: app.config por ejemplo tiene la conexion a la base de datos.. si fuera adentro del exe, como modificarias la misma cuando cambias de pc? no se porque se ve mas prolijo realmente...